# Graphs in 3 dimensions

Tags: graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

I have a desired graph as here:  the dashed line is just for perspective representation.  I tried with `LayeredGraphPlot` and `GraphPlot3D` but I don't know how I can show perceptively in 3 dimensions with `LayeredGraphPlot` or a curved lines in `GraphPlot3D`.

The scales in schematic picture are completely arbitrary but in order to achieve the graph, also showing the axes of coordinators are not needed, I should have presented here to be more clear! and stacking `i ,j, k, l, m, n` on the vertex (small circle on shape) can be desired.

[image]

For version 10: here is a problem at which I have encountered in running the David G.Stork code:

[image]

For version 9: although I don't write `show` in the last line but I just want to present the problem is related to create graph!

```
ef[pts_List, e_] := {Arrowheads[{0, .05, 0}], 
Arrow[BezierCurve[{pts[[1]], pts[[1]] + {0, 0, 1}, 
  pts[[2]] + {0, 0, 1}, pts[[2]]}]]};

myfig = Graph[{Style[1 -> 2, Thickness[0.005], Yellow], 
  Style[1 -> 4, Yellow, Dashing[0.02]], Style[1 -> 6, Yellow], 
   Style[2 -> 3, Green], Style[3 -> 4, Green], Style[4 -> 5, Green], 
   Style[5 -> 6, Green]}, EdgeShapeFunction -> ef, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {2, 0, 1}, 2 -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   3 -> {1, -1, 0}, 4 -> {2, -1, 0}, 5 -> {3, -1, 0}, 
   6 -> {4, 0, 0}}, Background -> LightGray]
```

But the output will be as below (just for showing output)
[image]

Comment: Try with `Graphics3D[ ]` instead

Comment: I can't curve smoothly lines in Graphics3D, they are sharply curved!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ef[pts_List, e_] :=
  {Arrowheads[{0, .05, 0}],
   Arrow[
    BezierCurve[
     {pts[[1]],
      pts[[1]] + {0, 0, 1},
      pts[[2]] + {0, 0, 1}, 
      pts[[2]]}]]};

myfig = Graph[
  {Style[1 -> 2, Thickness[0.005], Yellow], 
   Style[1 -> 4, Yellow, Dashing[0.02]], Style[1 -> 6, Yellow], 
   Style[2 -> 3, Green], Style[3 -> 4, Green], Style[4 -> 5, Green], 
   Style[5 -> 6, Green]},

  EdgeShapeFunction -> ef,

  VertexCoordinates -> {1 -> {2, 0, 1},
    2 -> {0, 0, 0},
    3 -> {1, -1, 0},
    4 -> {2, -1, 0},
    5 -> {3, -1, 0},
    6 -> {4, 0, 0}},
  Background -> LightGray];

Show[myfig,
 Graphics3D[
  {Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -3, 0}}],
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}],
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {5, -1, 0}}]}}
  ]]
```

[image]

Comment: So much thanks, Although I can understand most of the process of your code but I can't re construct your shape. I encounter to this message: Objects of "unequal length in {2.,0.}+{0,0,1} cannot be combined", "Objects of unequal length in {0.,0.}+{0,0,1} cannot be combined" ,"Objects of unequal length in {2.,0.}+{0,0,1} cannot be combined"!!!

Comment: Your vertex coordinates must be *three*-dimensional, i.e., `{0,0,0}` and `{1, -1, 0}`.  You should just copy my code and run it directly.

Comment: I just copy your code and run. because I can't upload a picture in comment, I am uploading that in the main question. please take a look at that.

Comment: @user36028 - start with a fresh kernel.

Comment: I started a fresh kernel! I even use of version 9, however the previous message does not appear again but another surprising message appears I upload that

Comment: @user36028 - don't post pictures of your code; post your code in code blocks.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, I wrote the code instead of picture but the output must be as a picture. because I want to show the result. If I copy to `code` place, output will be not show as I want.

Comment: @David G. Stork, With so much thanks to you after using 10.3 version of mathematica every thing was good.